# What's the equivalent of require('deferred') in "import from" with node -v >= 13

Tags: node.js, node-modules, deferred

I'm not a node expert but as far as I could understand 'require' instructions are no longer in use by default with node version higher than 12.
I'm migrating an app written with an old version but I stumble upon the import module instruction.
I used to
`require('deferred')`

But I cannot find the equivalent with the import from instructions.
I've tried many combination around

```
import deferred from 'deferred';
import * as deferred from deferred;
...
var d = new deferred();
```

But I could not get it to work.
It's really unclear how this import module works.
Could anyone light me on this?

Thanks :)

Comment: can you either mark my answer as accepted or post your own answer and accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks eol for your reply.

I managed to get it to work using

```
import Deferred from 'deferred';
const d =  Deferred();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred/blob/master/deferred.js#L150) deferred uses `module.exports` to export a factory function called `createDeferred`. So you should definitely be able to do the following using es-module imports:

```
import deferred from "deferred";

const deferredInstance = new deferred();
```